# Newer version of osgified guava library

Tags: java, osgi, guava

I'm aware of the [guava-osgi project site](http://code.google.com/p/guava-osgi/). But the latest avaiable version there is guava-r11.0.1

That seems a bit outdated (see [history](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReleaseHistory) of the guava-libraries project).

Does anybody know a source for an osgified guava bundle newer than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that since version 12, Guava is already an OSGi bundle, so the guava-osgi project is no longer required.

Comment: I had checked guava-14.0-rc1.jar and that is not a OSGI Bundle. But you are right. The official release guava-14.0.1.jar is.